# Jackson deserialization into field from subnode?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, gson

I have a class

```
public class Foo {
    String foo;
    String bar;
}
```

and JSON

```
{
  "foo": "foo",
  "bar": {
    "bar": "bar"
  }
}
```

Can I deserialize it using any json library without writing adapters/serializers to specific class.

Maybe some of gson's adapters has needed behavior? 
But I didn't find adapter to field. I'd like to write annotation like `@MyJsonExpandAnnotation("bar.bar")` but I can't find adapter with access to Field.

Comment: I'm not sure about annotation but https://github.com/google/gson google's gson is easy to use. You haven't need the define any class/enum to pre map any json.

Comment: Yes, but I have a lot classes and I can't write custom deserializer for them. Also I have another fields and I don't want to lose gson's under the hood work and handle only my specified fields. Now I am trying to find something I can use inside of ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you would use without your given annotation example is

```
public class Foo {
    String foo;
    Bar bar;
}

public class Bar{
    String bar;     
}
```

There is an open [suggestion](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/512) for it tho.

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems like it will be long wait to get solution from Jackson. 
For your answer, I don't want create another class. I want only perform flat map on json node.

Comment: @Monk3D Yes and that is not supported afaik.